# determine which named captures are present in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

Given a regular expression with named captures, is it possible to determine which named captures are present in the re?

Note: I only have the regular expression - I don't have a string which matches the re. I want to know if there is a way to look into the structure of the re and find all of the named captures used in the re.

Comment: For sake of completeness, I'll mention [Regexp::Parser](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Parser). As of 2011, it does not deal with modern regexp features from the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s not possible in the general case, because someone could have a `(??{....})` code insert that turns into something that uses a named capture of a hitherto unseen name during match execution time.

In a specific case you might be able to dig into the underlying structure from the C API.  `Devel::Peek` suggests some places you might want to poke around:

```
% perl -MDevel::Peek -le 'Dump qr/(?<foo>\w+) (?&foo)/'
SV = IV(0x8033ac) at 0x8033b0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x803d40
  SV = REGEXP(0x8173d8) at 0x803d40
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (OBJECT,POK,FAKE,pPOK)
    PV = 0x216fc0 "(?^:(?<foo>\\w+) (?&foo))"
    CUR = 24
    LEN = 0
    STASH = 0x803b50    "Regexp"
    EXTFLAGS = 0x600000 (USE_INTUIT_NOML,USE_INTUIT_ML)
    INTFLAGS = 0x1
    NPARENS = 1
    LASTPAREN = 0
    LASTCLOSEPAREN = 0
    MINLEN = 3
    MINLENRET = 3
    GOFS = 0
    PRE_PREFIX = 4
    SEEN_EVALS = 0
    SUBLEN = 0
    SUBBEG = 0x0
    ENGINE = 0x162b60
    MOTHER_RE = 0x80fab0
    PAREN_NAMES = 0x80fa40
    SUBSTRS = 0x2044b0
    PPRIVATE = 0x206360
    OFFS = 0x204280
```

For example, `PAREN_NAMES` looks promising.

But that seems like a lot of work.  What do you want to do this for?

Answer (score 3):

You might look at [`YAPE::Regex::Explain`](http://p3rl.org/YAPE%3a%3aRegex%3a%3aExplain). Other posts seem to suggest that http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl is a frontend for it, but to be sure its not hard to install and use.

I'm not sure how well it does named captures and certainly, as tchrist already said, there are cases which will be (probably) impossible.